# Python - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: python, object, tensorflow, detection

Was following an Object Detection tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgpfk6eYxJA

Set up Tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0 Cuda 9.0 Cudnn 7 When I run the train.py
I recieve an error that says:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQfH2.jpg

When I used Tensorflow-gpu version 1.5.0 (Just like in the video) I got an error that Said: " non_max_suppression() got an unexpected keyword argument 'score_threshold' "

Upon research I got to know that i have to use Tensorflow 1.9 or above to avoid this error.

I've tried implementing everything in order for like 3 times now and this error remains.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5056) they say you need even 1.9 version exactly.

Comment: Exactly! I saw that link that's why I switched to 1.9.0 But then got this error @AlexL

Comment: Ok, understood. I'm not acquainted with Tensorflow, may be this way will somehow help you. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc#L1278) is implementation of CheckNotInComputeAsync. Though that is 1.10 version. Try to manually insert this function in your 1.9 version and recompile. Or does this function already exist in 1.9 in other library?..

Comment: Tensorflow 1.9 doesnt have a op_kernel.cc file in core\framework :| @AlexL

Comment: Since the function is not complex, you could try to just replace its entry by those lines with appropriate substitutions.

Comment: Nope. I dont get it @AlexL